# Parsing groupings of strings (Python)

Tags: python

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
[["Name1","ID1","DDY1", "CALL1", "WHEN1"], ["Name2","ID2","DDY2", "CALL2", "WHEN2"],...];
```

This string was taken from a website. There can be any amount of groupings. How could I parse this string and print just the Name variables of each grouping?

Answer (score 5):

Hope I understood well.

```
>>> import json
>>> a = json.loads('[["Name1","ID1","DDY1", "CALL1", "WHEN1"], ["Name2","ID2","DDY2", "CALL2", "WHEN2"]]')
>>> [x[0] for x in a]
[u'Name1', u'Name2']
>>>
```

Comment: Then you need to show the full string. It could be a mangled json or something else entirely.

Comment: You may need to strip a trailing comma after the last grouping. Throw the string into jslint - it will tell you what's wrong. Then massage the string so it works and do the above. You should *really* avoid using eval on a string taken from another website.

Comment: Also, the string you are passing to json.loads should be a unicode object. Check that, or decode appropriately from utf-8 or whatever encoding.

Comment: Problem at line 1 character 194: Expected '(end)' and instead saw ';'.

Comment: Do I put [u'Name1', u'Name2'] in my IDE also or is that only for shell?

Comment: oh, it was just to show the output, if the 'Name' strings are what you are after.

Answer (score 3):

```
import ast
y = ast.literal_eval(input)
[x[0] for x in y]
```

Thanks to @stephan for pointing me in the right direction with ast.literal_eval. As described by the documentaion:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or
>   a string containing a Python
>   expression. The string or node
>   provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures:
>   strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating
>   strings containing Python expressions
>   from untrusted sources without the
>   need to parse the values oneself.

Note: this is new functionality in Python 2.6.

Comment: Suggest `ast.literal_eval()` instead of `eval`.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. I knew it was around and I was searching for it. http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html ftw.

Comment: You are welcome. Another tiny improvement: `str` is a built-in class, hence I wouldn't use this name in the list comprehension.